# Ctrl+Mouse-wheel not working with intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

If I use shift+mousewheel-up/down it will open this extremely annoying window.

I am not sure what this tool is called, I have checked my keyboard and searched for shift-mousewheel up or down and there are not shortcuts assigned to it.

Its worth noting it does scroll left or right as I intended it to. But the popup comes up always.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by **getting rid of the `imwheel`** package.

From my observations, it was sending additional keystrokes of the keys pressed in the moment of mouse scrolling. That was not an issue in situations such as horizontal scrolling in browsers (these don't have `double-shift` or `double-ctrl` keymappings), so it was quite difficult to locate the source of the problem.

### Tip

Try to figure out what input your keyboard is sending when scrolling and pressing keys such as `Ctrl`, then think about which process might be affecting this action.